# How to set Docker Desktop proxy settings from command line

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I'm working on a script that automatically sets a bunch of different proxy settings for a work thing. Without going into work specific details, it would be convenient if I could also set Docker Desktop for Mac's proxy settings from the command line.

I've read all the documentation I could get my hands on. Everything points to doing it from the UI. Does this functionality exist and I just haven't found it? Or am I spinning my wheels looking for something that isn't there?

Comment: did you try to set up a proxy over [~/.docker/config.json](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/) file?

Comment: I did. My team and I noticed that some proxy settings used the ~/.docker/config.json file while others were using the manual settings in the UI. We haven't experimented with going back to system settings yet. However, it seemed silly that we wouldn't be able to control the Docker Desktop app from the command line.

Comment: If I got it correctly from [this page](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/enterprise/admin/configure/mac-admin/) UI is using **/Library/Application Support/Docker/DockerDesktop/admin-settings.json** as config file. This can be the case, could you check that file if it's aligned with your UI. If it is then you can change that file according to your need.

Comment: I've run the find command again my whole laptop and not found it. On my machine, there's also no /Library/Application Support/..

That looks like an OSX path, which is what I'm using. I guess